# PHP basic upload file script

Tags: php, html, upload

This is my first time attempting to upload a file via PHP.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form role="form" action="api/upload.php" id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="file" />
   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Now here is the PHP script in reference "api/upload.php":

```
<?php
$target_dir = "files\\";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo $uploadOk . "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], $target_file)) {
   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else{
     echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
} 
?>
```

This may be a logic error.  I'm not sure.  Regardless, I keep getting the message:

> Sorry, there was an error uploading your file

When I echo out $uploadOk, it remains as 1. How can I find my error?

Comment: Clearly the `move_uploaded_file()` operation failed.  What are the runtime values of the arguments to that function?  Does the target directory exist?  Can the PHP process write to it?

Comment: Your error messages are WRONG. your actual message should be "your file was uploaded, but there was a problem moving it". which means you should investigate WHY the move call failed. And note that your overall uplaod checking needs work too. You simply assume uploads never fail. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. check for data in $_FILES doesn't mean an upload succeeded. Failed uploads will STILL populate $_FILES. but unless `['error']` is 0 (aka UPLOAD_ERR_OK), you can't TRUST any of the other $_FILES information.

Comment: The form is on the main page.  The PHP script is in a folder.  I have another folder called 'files'.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are getting a string for `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`? And are you sure you shouldn't be using `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` instead of `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]`

Should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Notes:-

`$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` is just the name of the uploaded file. `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` is the temporary file that holds the content.

Hope this helps.

[Edit 1]

I was wrong about adding a `value="submit"` attribute to the button. `name="submit"` attribute is sufficient for the `isset($_POST["submit"))` check.